# Equation in radicals $x^7+7x^3-7x^2+7x+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solve the following equation in radicals.
$$x^7+7x^3-7x^2+7x+1=0$$
It's obvious that this equation has no rational roots.

And what is the rest?

Comment: Why is this equation supposed to have radical roots?

Comment: It is easy to prove that the derivative is positive, so the polynomial increases and by intermediate value theorem, it has exactly one (irrational) root, in the interval $(-1/2,0)$. What else can be said about it? WolframAlpha doesn't solve it.

Comment: @ajotatxe Because one of my students said that it's possible.

Comment: hm then let us know what your Student says

Comment: @ajotatxe The Galois group is $D_{14}$ which is solvable.

Comment: @user399601 It says that there is solution with $\sqrt[7]{.}$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes. There is a solution involving $2$nd and $7$th roots. You can see that from the Galois group.

Comment: @user399601 how did you find the Galois group?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X.pdf

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Do you mind to share how you solved it? Thanks

Comment: @Ovi I found mistake in my computations. I am sorry.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Maybe the student also had a mistake in their solution. Have you asked them to show you his/her answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Galois group of the polynomial is $D_{14}$, thus it is solvable.

[RadiRoot](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/radiroot.html) is an implementation of the algorithm described in this paper:
http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/distler/Diplom.pdf. This is the output of RadiRoot:

Let $\zeta_7$ be a primitive $7$-th root of unity and
$$\omega_1 = \sqrt[7]{ - \frac{5}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{5} - \frac{4}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{4} - \frac{4}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{3} - \frac{5}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{2} - \frac{3}{7^3}}.$$

Then a root is

$$\left(-14 \zeta _7^5+28 \zeta _7^4+28 \zeta _7^3-14 \zeta _7^2+21\right) \omega
   _1^6+\left(7 \zeta _7^5-7 \zeta _7^4-7 \zeta _7^3+7 \zeta _7^2\right) \omega
   _1^5+\left(7 \zeta _7^4+7 \zeta _7^3+7\right) \omega _1^4+\left(\zeta _7^5-2 \zeta
   _7^4-2 \zeta _7^3+\zeta _7^2-5\right) \omega _1^3+\left(\zeta _7^5-\zeta _7^4-\zeta
   _7^3+\zeta _7^2\right) \omega _1^2+\omega _1.$$

**Edit.**

For example, let $\zeta_7 = e^{-\frac{4 i \pi }{7}}$.
Then we have
$$\omega_1 = \sqrt[7]{\frac{-3-8 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+10 \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{7}\right)}{7^3}} \approx 0.43566,$$
and a root is:
\begin{align}
\left(56 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+28 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)+21\right) &\omega
   _1^6
\\-\left(14 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+14 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right) &\omega
   _1^5
\\+\left(14 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+7\right) &\omega _1^4
\\-\left(4 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)+5\right) &\omega _1^3
\\-\left(2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right) &\omega _1^2
\\+\ &\omega _1 \approx -0.125215.
\end{align}

Comment: But $\zeta_7$ we can not write in radicals.

Comment: You can find an expression of $\zeta_7$ by radicals in *Tabelle 4.1* from the paper I linked.

Comment: I mean a real radical. I think it's impossible.

Comment: The usual definition in Galois theory of "write in terms of radicals" allows one to use $\zeta_n$ for any $n$. So I think cafaxo gave a valid answer.

Comment: @Mark If so cafaxo solves this problem!

Comment: Also: $\zeta_7 = \frac12 (R + \sqrt{R^2-4})$ where $R = 2 \cos(2 \pi/7)$ is a root of $R^3+R^2-2R-1 = 0$, and that latter equation can be solved in terms of radicals with Cardano's formula.

Comment: @Mark No! Cardano's formula does not work here because $\Delta<0$, but I understood you. Thank you!

Comment: That's true, to write this real number $R$ in terms of radicals, you can't avoid taking a radical of a complex number.

Comment: @cafaxo Can you check a computation of $\omega_1$. I think it's not true.

Comment: I've checked this result in Mathematica. **FullSimplify** manages to prove it directly.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg There is a purely real expression for the real root of the polynomial using trigonometric functions. Do you want me to add this to my answer?

Comment: @cafaxo Yes of course! Can you check the following: $\omega_1 = \sqrt[7]{ - \frac{4}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{5} - \frac{4}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{4} - \frac{5}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{3} - \frac{5}{7^3}\zeta_{7}^{6} - \frac{3}{7^3}}.$

Comment: To clarify: $\omega_1$ is not a root of the polynomial, but a primitive element of the extension $\mathbb{Q}_f(\zeta_7) / \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$. Where $\mathbb{Q}_f$ is the splitting field of the polynomial.

Comment: I've edited my answer.